# Barnes Hut Algorithm sub-quadrants

Tags: algorithm, orbital-mechanics

I'm trying to implement the Barnes-Hut algorithm. My current pseudocode for inserting is:

1. if node is empty, place an object into it (object being a particle/planet)
2. if node is a leaf, swap it with a object that holds center-of-mass info, then reinsert the swapped out object and the inserting object
3. if node is a center-of-mass object, update it with the inserting object and move into the correct child quadrant

But when I look at all the barnes-hut diagrams, they all have quadrants of equal size. Does this mean that when I get to step #2 I'll have to place the center-of-mass object at the exact center of a sub-quadrant?

Comment: The "center-of-mass info" should be its *position* and the total sum of the masses, if you "place" it at the exact center you are losing that information.

Comment: So all those subquadrant box sizes, are they just for visuals and have no real meaning? Each box contains 1 object but the box size is irrelevant?

Comment: If you are referring to an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) space subdvision, that's the data structure used to store the objects, it's fundamental to achive the algorithm efficiency [promises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation#Calculating_the_force_acting_on_a_body).